# Media query is working in IE but not in google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, media-queries

I try to apply some CSS styles based on the screen size, however, the media query is not working in Google Chrome but it works on Internet Explorer, any ideas how to fix this issue? 
- I couldn`t find a reasonable solution to my problem, i searched the internet with suggestions but nothing good yet.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
.container {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
.container {
    max-width: 100%;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.container {
    max-width: 100%;
}
}
```

Comment: Is your CSS contained with a separate file? I know that sometimes Chrome needs a hard refresh before it reads the file back in again.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache and history?

Comment: What is the expected result of your CSS? Right now, you have the same rule applied to all breakpoints, with the exception that one includes an `!important` annotation.

Comment: yes @MichaelvE, is in another file...what you suggest in this case?

Comment: @EvikGhazarian, I haven`t, i will try now clearing my cache.

Comment: @denmch, i expect my result to make the container full width. Which i assume that if i will have only the 768 width will apply even if the window size will be 1200+?

Comment: Go into Chrome's developer tools and check if the style sheet being read in is the right document. If not, then this looks like a caching issue - Chrome has the CSS file already so won't get it again. If so, try a hard refresh: [Ctrl] + [F5]. This should work. If not, some add a time stamp to the end of the CSS file name, that forces the browser to get it again because it updates every second: href="styles.css?ts=<?=time()?>&quot;". But, this isn't good for performance as browsers will always be forced to get the file. Add a version number to your file name would solve this: style.css?v1.2

Comment: `max-width` doesn't make things full width. It means that they can't be more than that size. It's possible for children to be larger than their parents, and break out. `max-width` refers to the maximum width of the current selector with reference to its parent. If the parent (e.g., `body`) is 1200px, `max-width` says that `.container` can't be any wider than 1200px. it doesn't say that it has to be 1200px. That's `width` rather than `max-width`. The width must be controlled by another rule or condition.

Comment: Problem solved: It was a caching issue. I cleared my cache and now everything is fine. Thanks guys.